# How to call a webservice when in localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I do not have IIS, I use my localhost that comes with Visual Studio, I am not sure how to make a service call work if I am using localhost. It tells me "Unable to connect to remote server" , Is there a way I can make a webservice call work using localhost?. Here is my code:

```
    public void CallService()
    {
        WebRequest requestweb = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/WebServices/MyTestService/HelloWorld");
        requestweb.Method = "GET";
        //Line below returns "Unable to connect to remote server"
        WebResponse response = requestweb.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Would truly appreciate an advice on this. Thank you

Comment: have you done some sanity tests to check if the service answers? take the url and run it in your browser...

Comment: if you are using the localhost from vs it usually means that you have to add the port number to the call..,

Comment: Hello, great tip, i did put the url like this: http: //localhost:53197/WebServices/MyTestService/HelloWorld, but it returns a 404. This how I have it set up. Under my Web project I added a folder called 'WebServices' and under it I have my web service but it doesnt seem to be finding it..

Comment: Is this a ASMX or WCF service you are trying to call?

Comment: I figured it out, i was calling a GET while it was expecting a POST... thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the website you're trying to connect to in your favorite web browser. Copy the value from your location bar and paste it as the parameter to `WebRequest.Create`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple Java TCP tunnel.

Download **[this](http://jcbserver.uwaterloo.ca/cs436/software/tgui/tcpTunnelGUI.shtml)** Java app & just tunnel the traffic back.

In command prompt, you'd then run the java app like this... Let's assume you want external access on port 80 and your standard debug environment runs on port 1088...

```
java -jar tunnel.jar 80 localhost 1088
```